# Transferring files between servers using commands

Tags: windows-server-2008

At my workplace I have various Sql Server instanced, on different Windows Servers. When I make a backup of a Sql Server database instance, it sits on that Windows Server and not on my machine so to see the file (e.g. be able to right click > Properties on it), I need to remote desktop into that server.

However, what commands are available to copy the file to my desktop/machine? I have seen people run a command to paste a file to my desktop, from another, by typing something like C$ in Windows Explorer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "C$" stuff is called "administrative shares", and is something you really want disabled for security reasons - google it.

But assuming administrative shares are on, you can type something like the following from your own machine: open a shell, and type "copy \server.domain.com\C$\path\to\backup.dump c:\local\path" , assuming the backup is on C: - for another partition, guess what you have to change? :). This requires that your local account matches an account (w/administrative privileges) on the remote server as well.

A better thing would be explicitly sharing the folder on the server that has the backups, which lets you control the access restrictions explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You could run an FTP server on one of the machines, and then use an [FTP batch script](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269) to copy the file(s) you require.

Comment: There's some built in commands in Windows Server. I was actually trying to find what they are, although your answer is valid. :)